# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0 problem with Snackbar

Tags: java, android, android-snackbar

I'm learning about android and client - server applications and I have little problem with Snackbar.
I really can't find anything connected with Snackbar

This is my error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:360)
    at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:97)
    at com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:230)
    at com.example.klient.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:54)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6614)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6591)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:786)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25948)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

This is MainActivity.java:54:

```
.make(constraintLayout, result, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

And there are my classes

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
private Button button;
private EditText editText;
private static int result;


public static void setResult(Integer value) {
    result = value;
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = String.valueOf(editText.getText());
                int toSend = Integer.parseInt(text);
                SendToServer send = new SendToServer();
            send.execute(toSend);
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(constraintLayout, result, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.show();


        }
    });

}
```

}

```
public class SendToServer extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer> {


@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
    try{
        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.43.68", 60080);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new
                OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        bw.write(integers[0]);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.flush();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        int result = br.read();
        return result;

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
    MainActivity.setResult(integer);
}
```

}

and my activity_main.xml file

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
tools:context="com.example.klient.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="164dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="164dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="601dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="159dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="159dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
    android:text="Oblicz"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="111dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="535dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="87dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="87dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="151dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I can't find this I am asking for help.

Comment: Double check all your xml files to make sure there is no error in each. This type of error message can be caused by an issue in one of your xml files, and the log isn't very helpful in pointing out where the issue might be.

Comment: I think it is snackbar. you are passing the value of result while asynctask is still executing, still i am not sure.. cause logcat doesnt give any specific issue

Comment: Oh, that's possible, but how to avoid that situation with asynctask is still executing?

Comment: you can try this. `if(send.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(constraintLayout, result, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.show();}` or move the snackbar code in `onPostExcecute()`

Comment: Right now it looks like its freezing when im pushing button

Comment: move the snackbar code to `onPostExecute()` and see.

Comment: Sorry for that newbie question, but how access to constraintLayout?

Comment: I did it like that:
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(MainActivity.constraintLayout, result, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.show();

But now I have that mistake

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7d in .make line

Comment: Ok, I get it, I dont need MainActivity behind constraintLayout but still I am getting this error:

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7d

Comment: Ok, solved, I need to wrap integer into String.valueOf in Snackbar, thank you for everything